# Rectangle and trapezium inscribed in a triangle

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus

In a triangle $ABC$, $\,D$ and $E$ are points on $AB$ and $AC$ respectively such that $DE$ $\parallel$ $BC$. Draw $DP$ and $EQ$ perpendicular to $BC$ with $P$ and $Q$ on $BC$. Let $\frac{BD}{AD} = \lambda$.

(a) Find $\,area(\square DPQE)$ in terms of $\,area(\triangle ABC)$ and $\lambda$.

(b) Find the value of $\,\lambda$ for which $area (\square DPQE)$ is maximum.

(c) If the condition $DE\,\parallel BC$ is dropped, for what choices of $D$ and $E\,$ is $\,area(\square DPQE)$ maximised? (without doing any further calculation)

Part (a) is easy. It can be found using similar triangles. Part (b) is also easy. $area(\square DPQE)$ is maximum when $\lambda = 1$ i.e., when $D$ and $E$ are the mid-points of $AB$ and $AC$ respectively. I am stuck with part (c).

Comment: (Esp if you're allowed to do further calculations) What is your guess for when the area is maximized? It might help to consider extreme scenarios.

Comment: @Subhandu, when E is on  A and D is close to B.